# Metal shader 3D texture lookup

Tags: ios, fragment-shader, texture-mapping, metal, metalkit

I created a 3D texture from a LUT file on iOS as follows:

```
    let dim = 33
    let textureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor()
    textureDescriptor.textureType = .type3D
    textureDescriptor.pixelFormat = .rgba32Float
    textureDescriptor.width = dim
    textureDescriptor.height = dim
    textureDescriptor.depth = dim
    textureDescriptor.usage = .shaderRead

    let texture = device.makeTexture(descriptor: textureDescriptor)

    texture!.replace(region: MTLRegionMake3D(0, 0, 0, dim, dim, dim),
                    mipmapLevel:0,
                    slice:0,
                    withBytes:values!,
                    bytesPerRow:dim * MemoryLayout<Float>.size * 4,
                    bytesPerImage:dim * dim * MemoryLayout<Float>.size * 4)
```

and then I try to use this LUT in fragment shader as follows:

```
 fragment half4 fragmentShader ( MappedVertex in [[ stage_in ]],
                              texture2d<float, access::sample> inputTexture [[ texture(0) ]],
                              texture3d<float, access::sample> lutTexture [[ texture(1) ]]
                              )
{
   constexpr sampler s(s_address::clamp_to_edge, t_address::clamp_to_edge, min_filter::linear, mag_filter::linear);
   float3 rgb = inputTexture.sample(s, in.textureCoordinate).rgb;

   float3 lookupColor = lutTexture.sample(s, rgb).rgb;
   return half4(half3(lookupColor), 1.h);
}
```

I am afraid that I'm not getting the correct results. Is everything in the code perfect? Am I sampling the 3d texture correctly?

Comment: It's hard to answer this because you're leaving a lot of information out. Where does `values` come from and how do you know its format? If there's any padding/alignment, then you may have the bytes-per-row and bytes-per-image wrong. Why are you "afraid that [you're] not getting the correct results"? What were you expecting? What did you actually get?

Comment: values holds a sequence of rgba values and is 33*33*33*4*MemoryLayout<Float>.size bytes in size. It is a LUT table. My doubt is whether shader code that calculates lookupColor is correct or not.

Comment: Having done similar things in the past, this looks correct to me. Again, what are you expecting, and exactly what results are you getting?

Comment: I believe then my LUT is not perfect or there are some interpolation issues with the sampler.

Comment: hi, I face the same problem with you, did you find any solution to fix interpolation issues?